# 1 parent nodetype with 2 subnodetypes - show all subnodes in a viewlist

Tags: 7, views, nodes

Here is the situation: Using D7 and views 3.

I have made a nodetype 1.

I have two nodetypes 1a and 1b (node referenced to nodetype 1).

I want to show all nodes (1a and 1b) attached to nodetype 1 in a views-list when showing nodetype 1.

Contextual filters can only show one subnodetype correct.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `Relationships` to pull in data from your other nodes. When you have defined your relations then you will be able to use these in each fields setting:

```
Relationships:
field_1a 
field_1b

Fields:
// Uses no relation
// Will display title from content-type 1
Content: Title
// Relation field_1a
// Will display title from content-type 1a
Content: Title 
// Relation field_1b
// Will display title from content-type 1b
Content: Title
```